# How to substitute a return value based on the return type of a method with Resharper Macros?

Tags: resharper

So I have created a basic resharper template that creates Nunit Structure for me.

```
    [Test]
    public void $Method$_ShouldCall_service_$Method$()
    {
        //arrange
        $END$
        //act
        var result = _sut.$Method$($parameter$);

        //assert
        _serviceFake.AssertWasCalled(x => x.$Method$($parameter$));
    }
```

If the return type of:

```
    _sut.$Method$($parameter$);
```

is void I would like the result to be:

```
    [Test]
    public void $Method$_ShouldCall_service_$Method$()
    {
        //arrange
        $END$
        //act
        _sut.$Method$($parameter$);

        //assert
        _serviceFake.AssertWasCalled(x => x.$Method$($parameter$));
    }
```

[Based on this post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/10/14/templates-galore-extending-functionality-with-macros/) I can get the return type of the method. The question is how to I remove:

```
    var result =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done. The Live Template mechanism doesn't have support for conditional insertion. What this means is that you need yet another Live Template macro that checks whether the containing type is `void` and if it is, yields an empty string, otherwise yields a `return` (don't forget the space).

You should be able to use `GetPresentableName` as before, and simply compare it with `void`. Then, you should be able to construct and return a `TextLookupItem` as before.